# Returning Unique SQL rows when data appears multiple times using max(date)

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL which holds a complete event history for my key management system.  Each event is either a 'Pickup' or a 'Return', i.e. a key being collected or a key being returned.

The table holds the following information

- e_ID PK - Unique ID
- e_KeyName
- e_State either 'Pickup' or 'Return'
- e_datestamp - the date and time of the event  (get date())
- e_user the Windows login Username for each user

Example:

```
1   Key_001  Pickup  date   User1
2   Key_002  Pickup  date   User2
3   Key_002  Return  date   User2
4   Key_003  Pickup  date   User2
```

What I need to do is display all rows which are currently 'Pick-Up' and DON'T have a newer 'Return' row.

In the example above I would need to return Key_003 and Key_001 as they are both marked 'Pickup', but not Key_002 as it has been returned.

If I added a 5 row of

```
5   Key_002  Pickup  date   User3
```

Then I would expect to return this row as well, as per below

```
1   Key_001  Pickup  date   User1
4   Key_003  Pickup  date   User2
5   Key_002  Pickup  date   User3
```

My plan is then to check the datestamp and compare this to the current Server time to determine how long the key has been in 'Pickup' - this i can do.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I don't really have any SQL query to show where I am to do as I'm a bit lost.

This is SQL Server i'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was not clear about which version of SQL Server are you using, apart of that always is useful to have a clear definition about your tables involves.

```
DECLARE @MyTable AS TABLE
(
  KeyCode VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  TypeMovement CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  DateMovement DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
  UserMovement VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable (   KeyCode ,
                         TypeMovement ,
                         DateMovement ,
                         UserMovement
                     )
VALUES (   'Key_001' ,            -- KeyCode - varchar(25)
           'Pickup' ,            -- TypeMovement - char(10)
           SYSDATETIME() , -- DateMovement - datetime2
           'User1'              -- UserMovement - varchar(20)
       ),
       (   'Key_001' ,            -- KeyCode - varchar(25)
           'Return' ,            -- TypeMovement - char(10)
           SYSDATETIME() , -- DateMovement - datetime2
           'User1'              -- UserMovement - varchar(20)
       ),
       (   'Key_002' ,            -- KeyCode - varchar(25)
           'Pickup' ,            -- TypeMovement - char(10)
           SYSDATETIME() , -- DateMovement - datetime2
           'User2'              -- UserMovement - varchar(20)
       ),
       (   'Key_003' ,            -- KeyCode - varchar(25)
           'Pickup' ,            -- TypeMovement - char(10)
           SYSDATETIME() , -- DateMovement - datetime2
           'User2'              -- UserMovement - varchar(20)
       );

; WITH MyCTE AS
(
  SELECT KeyCode,
         TypeMovement,
         LEAD(TypeMovement) OVER(PARTITION BY KeyCode ORDER BY DateMovement) AS NextMovementAssociated,
         DateMovement,
         UserMovement

  FROM @MyTable
)
SELECT MyCTE.KeyCode,MyCTE.TypeMovement,MyCTE.DateMovement,MyCTE.UserMovement FROM MyCTE
WHERE MyCTE.NextMovementAssociated IS NULL AND MyCTE.TypeMovement='Pickup';
```

Comment: Great answer, that you so much. SQL Server version is 2016.